# Find an equation of the tangent line to the following curve at the given point. y = $e^{4x}$ cos πx, (0, 1)

Tags: calculus

Find an equation of the tangent line to the following curve at the given point.
y = $e^{4x}$ cos πx,    (0, 1)

I do not have a clue how to do this problem.

Comment: How much of the calculus have you studied? It doesn't change the method, but I want to know how much detail you need.

Comment: I am currently taking college calculus II

Comment: Also, is that supposed to be $e^{4x}$? If so, enclose 4x in braces like `e^{4x}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equation of tangent at point $P(x_{1},y_{1})$ to the curve $y=f(x)$ is $\displaystyle y-y_{1} = \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{(x_{1},y_{1})}[x-x_{1}].$

Where $\displaystyle \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{(x_{1},y_{1})}$ is $\bf{Slope \; of \; Tangencial \; Line.}$

So Here $y=\left[e^{4x}\cdot \cos (\pi x)\right]$ and point $P(0,1)$

Now $$\displaystyle \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{(0,1)} = \left[-e^{4x}\cdot \sin (\pi x)\cdot \pi+\cos(\pi x)\cdot 4e^{4x}\right]_{(0,1)} = 4$$

So equation of tangent is $$y-1 = 4(x-0)\Rightarrow 4x-y+1 =0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this the easy way.

$$y = e^{4x} \times (x\cos\pi x)$$
Product Rule twice then Chain Rule.
$$y' = e^{4x}(4\cos\pi x - \pi\sin\pi x)$$

Now plug and solve for the slope at $x=0$.

$$y'(0) = e^0(4-0) = 4$$

Now if we plug this into the definition for a line,

$$y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$$
$$y-1=4(x-0)$$
$$y=4x+1$$

There's our equation.